# Extract string between multiple words, using gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to isolate words from a string in R using -gsub-. I want to extract a name that can be found between either "(" and "(m)" (for males) or between "(" and "(f)". I am struggling to incorporate in one line of code.

```
name<-c("Dr. T. (Tom) Bailey (m), UCL- Physics" , "Dr. B.K. (Barbara) Blue (f), Oxford - Political Science")

malename<-gsub(".*\\) (.*) \\(m).*", "\\1", name)
femname<-gsub(".*\\) (.*) \\(f).*", "\\1", name)
```

The code above gives me the names for males and females separately, but ideally I want to obtain their lastname in one variable. This would involve some OR function (so (m) OR (f)), but I don't know how to incorporate this.

Comment: You mean you are looking for `".*\\) (.*) \\([mf]\\).*"`?

Comment: `gsub('(\\w+) \\([mf]\\)|.', '\\1', name)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to match either `m` or `f`, the best way to match them is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (or, in POSIX terminology, a bracket expression): `[mf]`.

Your regex will look like

```
".*\\)\\s+(.*)\\s+\\([mf]\\).*"
                     ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rVKfyD/2)

You may use the regex with `sub` to make sure only one regex match and  replacement are performed (see [online demo](https://ideone.com/GsqPDt)):

```
name<-c("Dr. T. (Tom) Bailey (m), UCL- Physics" , "Dr. B.K. (Barbara) Blue (f), Oxford - Political Science")
res <- sub(".*\\)\\s+(.*)\\s+\\([mf]\\).*", "\\1", name)
res
## => [1] "Bailey" "Blue"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, this works out. Unfortunately I now see that there are some names where the sex is not listed, e.g.: "Dr. T. (Tim) Ford, UCL- Physics". Can I use the comma as well in the command? Similarly, some names include an extra space after the gender identifier, ie: "Dr. T. (Tom) Bailey (m ), UCL- Physics". Would there be any way to deal with this as well?

Comment: Yes, use lazy matching (`.*?`) with the first and second dot and use an alternation `(?:\([mf]\)|,)`: [`sub(".*?\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?:\\([mf]\\)|,).*", "\\1", name)`](https://ideone.com/au2fRJ).

Comment: Thanks again, but the lazy matching doesn't seem to solve the extra space after the m (m ). In this example, it does not return the name. `name<-c("Dr. T. (Tom) Bailey (m ))` and then `sub(".*?\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?:\\([mf]\\)|,).*", "\\1", name)` returns an empty string.

Comment: Your examples did not inlcude that kind of input. To match these strings, you need to use `\s*` after `[mf]` to "allow" 0+ whitespaces. It does not matter if the dot is greedily or lazily quantified. Try [`sub(".*?\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?:\\(\\s*[mf]\\s*\\)|,).*", "\\1", name)`](https://ideone.com/7d4PYK).

Comment: this works perfectly, you've saved my day! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `sub`

```
sub("^[^)]+\\)\\s+(\\w+).*", "\\1", name)
#[1] "Bailey" "Blue"
```